# Sharepoint datetime control, how to stop taking today date

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013

I have put SharePoint Date Time control in asp.net application page...Problem is by default it is taking Today date how to "stop tanking today date"...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using own control instead of sp date control.

```
var dateControl = new DateTimeControl();
dateControl.ID = "anyId";
dateControl.DateOnly = true;         
dateControl.CssClassTextBox = "cssclass";
dateControl.LocaleId = Convert.ToInt32(SPContext.Current.RegionalSettings.LocaleId);
dateControl.OnValueChangeClientScript = "onApplyDateChangeValue(event)"; 

//if you want to set any value
dateControl.SelectedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("dateString", "dd.MM.yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

//Add to app page          
"elementID".Controls.Add(dateControl);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine

write below code in side click function:
if (!spCal2.IsDateEmpty)
    {
     lblShowdtae.Text = dtSPdate.SelectedDate.ToString();
    }